# how to get the variable of a php array echo onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdo

I've been able to get my arrays working to echo text from a database in HTML. Fine. However, I now want to send this text to another page onClick (JQuery or JavaScript). So here is what I already have (I know it's not sending anything, but this is not the problem right now) :

PHP

```
$h = "SELECT * FROM table";
$h=$pdo->prepare($h);
$h->execute();
$i=1;
while ($row = $h->fetch()) {
$text[$i] = $row['content'];
$id[$i] = $row['id'];
$i++;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 id="<?php echo $id[0]; ?>" onClick="edit(this)"><?php echo $text[0]; ?>
</h1>
<h2 id="<?php echo $id[1]; ?>" onClick="edit(this)"><?php echo $text[1]; ?></h2>
<p id="<?php echo $id[2]; ?>" onClick="edit(this)"><?php echo $text[2]; ?></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function edit(element) {
alert(element.id);
}
```

So, this gives me the "id" of the content in the database. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to get this information without having the "id" in the HTML tags, a way to click on the text and have the number that is inside the square brackets.

Example : you click on the text inside the "h1" tag and a pop up tells you what is the number in `<?php echo $text[2]; ?>`. In this case, I would like the number 2 to show up in the alert box, without using `id="<?php echo $id[2]; ?>"`.

Comment: So are you saying you want to have this: `<p><?php echo $text[2]; ?></p>` the when you click it, it gives you this value?: `$id[2]` or do you want the key to show `2` (from the `$id[2]`)?

Comment: If you want the value of `$id[2]` but don't want to display the value on the page anywhere, you will need ajax to call that from the database based on the value of `$text[2]`.